# spark-submit error: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

build.sbt

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
    organization := "com.me",
    version := "0.1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
)

lazy val counter = (project in file("counter")).
    settings(commonSettings:_*)
```

counter/build.sbt

```
name := "counter"
mainClass := Some("Counter")
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

val sparkVersion = "2.1.1";

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided";

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.2";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8" % sparkVersion;

libraryDependencies += "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.5.0";

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.1";
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test";

mergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", "unused", "UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x => (mergeStrategy in assembly).value(x)
}
```

counter.scala:

```
object Counter extends SignalHandler
{
    var ssc : Option[StreamingContext] = None;
    def main( args: Array[String])
```

Run

```
./spark-submit --class "Counter" --master spark://10.1.204.67:6066 --deploy-mode cluster file://counter-assembly-0.1.0.jar
```

Error:

```
17/06/21 19:00:25 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'Driver' on port 50140.
17/06/21 19:00:25 INFO WorkerWatcher: Connecting to worker spark://Worker@10.1.204.57:52476
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Counter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
```

Any idea? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I had the problem here [Failed to submit local jar to spark cluster: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662751/failed-to-submit-local-jar-to-spark-cluster-java-nio-file-nosuchfileexception). Now, I copied the jar into `spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin` and then run `./spark-submit --class "Counter" --master spark://10.1.204.67:6066 --deploy-mode cluster file://Counter-assembly-0.1.0.jar`

The spark cluster is of 2.1.0

But the jar was assembled in 2.1.1 and Scala 2.11.0.

Comment: Have you tried renaming counter.scala to **C**ounter.scala?

Comment: @TomLous No. I will try

Comment: @TomLous Just now, I tried, not working

Comment: Hmm, hard to tell without the entire project available. Some small pointers / unwanted advice though (probably won't help, but here  anyway). 1. Don't use scala 2.11.0, rather 2.11.11 2. Don't use semicolons in scala (very Java) 3. Why have 2 build.sbt files. 1 should be enough for such a small project? 4. Reorganise your code in a src/main/scala/ folder 5. Don't use var's (not very FP).
Sorry I couldn't help you, but if you could share the project code via github or so I or someone else could check it out quickly?

Comment: @TomLous Thanks. Just curious why complains the class name is wrong.

Comment: I _bet_ it's because the jar is not used correctly as you reference it using `file://counter-assembly-0.1.0.jar` not `target/scala-2.11/counter-assembly-0.1.0.jar`. In other words, where do you start `spark-submit` from?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I had the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662751/failed-to-submit-local-jar-to-spark-cluster-java-nio-file-nosuchfileexception. Now, I copied the jar into `spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin` and then run `./spark-submit --class "Counter" --master spark://10.1.204.67:6066 --deploy-mode cluster file://Counter-assembly-0.1.0.jar`

Comment: I read the documents and same similar posts again and again. It seems that what I did is right. but it does not work.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski where to put the jar and how to submit it?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski are you author of mastering apache spark 2?

Comment: @BAE Yes, I'm the author of the gitbook.

Answer (score 3):

It *appears* that you've just started developing Spark applications with Scala so for the only purpose to help you and the other future Spark developers, I hope to give you enough steps to get going with the environment.

### Project Build Configuration - build.sbt

It *appears* that you use multi-project sbt build and that's why you have two `build.sbt`s. For the purpose of fixing your issue I'd pretend you don't use this advanced sbt setup.

It *appears* that you use Spark Streaming so define it as a dependency (as `libraryDependencies`). You don't have to define the other Spark dependencies (like `spark-core` or `spark-sql`).

You should have `build.sbt` as follows:

```
organization := "com.me"
version := "0.1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
val sparkVersion = "2.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided"
```

### Building Deployable Package

With `build.sbt` above, you execute `sbt package` to build a deployable Spark application package that you eventually `spark-submit` to a Spark cluster.

You don't have to use `sbt assembly` for that...yet. I can see that you use Spark Cassandra Connector and other dependencies that could also be defined using `--packages` or `--jars` instead (which by themselves have their pros and cons).

```
sbt package
```

The size of the final `target/scala-2.11/counter_2.11-0.1.0.jar` is going to be much smaller than `counter-assembly-0.1.0.jar` you have built using `sbt assembly` because `sbt package` does not include the dependencies in a single jar file. That's expected and fine.

### Submitting Spark Application - spark-submit

After `sbt package` you should have the deployable package in `target/scala-2.11` as `counter-assembly-0.1.0.jar`.

You should just `spark-submit` with required options which in your case would be:

```
spark-submit \
  --master spark://10.1.204.67:6066
 target/scala-2.11/counter-assembly-0.1.0.jar
```

That's it.

---

Please note that:

1. `--deploy-mode cluster` is too advanced for the exercise (let's keep it simple and bring it back when needed)
2. `file://` makes things broken (or at least is superfluous)
3. `--class "Counter"` is taken care of by `sbt package` when you have a single Scala application in a project where you execute it. You can safely skip it.

Comment: thanks. but (1) after running `sbt package`, `counter_2.11-0.1.0.jar` in `target/scala-2.11`; (2) counter_2.11-0.1.0.jar is much smaller than `counter-assembly-0.1.0.jar`; (3) 6066 is port for rest; (4) I really would like to deploy jar to remote spark cluster in cluster mode. I read https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html again and again and tried but cannot make it work.

Comment: Improved my answer to answer your question from the comment above. _"I really would like to deploy jar to remote spark cluster in cluster mode"_ Why? Can you explain why you insist on doing `cluster` when you haven't even `spark-submit`ed the application using `client` mode **yet**? That's another issue and we should discuss it after we have this case closed. Don't you think?

Comment: I already tried `client mode` and it is working fine. But I prefer the cluster mode and submitting through rest apis. please view my update here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662751/failed-to-submit-local-jar-to-spark-cluster-java-nio-file-nosuchfileexception

Comment: So your question is about `spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster` then, isn't it? That was not clear from the question.

Comment: Can you go to http://10.1.204.67:8080 and take a screenshot of the first page of the standalone Master's web UI? Include the screenshot to your question please. Thanks!